# How to raise an alert dialog from BroadcastReceiver class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used a timer method in an `Activity` class. In that method I have an intent from `Activity` class to a `BroadcastReceiver` class.

This `BroadcastReceiver` class will call on every 15 minutes at background by using `AlarmManager`.

When I call the `BroadcastReceiver` class I would like to raise an `AlertDialog`.

```
public void timerMethod(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,
      BroadcastReceiverClass.class
    );

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
      QualityCallActivity.this,0, intent, 0
    );

    // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    firstTime, 60*1000, sender);
}
```

**BroadcastReceiverClass.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    dialogMethod();
}
```

How can I raise an `AlertDialog` from `BroadcastReceiver` class from a background process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: It is **not** possible.

Only Activity's can create/show dialogs. In fact, this has been asked more then once:

- [AlertDialog in BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432601/alertdialog-in-broadcastreceiver)
- [How can I display a dialog from an Android broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835160/how-can-i-display-a-dialog-from-an-android-broadcast-receiver)

Also, this would give a very bad user-experience:

- If the user is not in your application (let's say he's playing a
  Game) and your Dialog pops up every 15 minutes, this will be very
  annoying for him.
- If the user is in your application, there are several other (better
  suited) ways to notify him that something has been executed.

### Better suited ways

In fact, you can create/show a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) from an `BroadcastReceiver`. This `Toast` will also bee shown when the user is not "in your application".

Also, you can send a Notification (shown in the Notification-Bar at the top of your screen) from a `BroadcastReceiver`. A [tutorial on how to do this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (it does not differ from how you do it in an Activity, except that you use the passed `Context`-Object from the `onReceive`-method).

The Notification will also be shown when the user is not "in your application" and is IMO the best solution to this problem.

Comment: While you have good points about whether an `AlertDialog` is the best option, it most certainly **is** possible to show one from a `BroadcastReceiver`.  As I point out in my answer, it works if your `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class to your activity.  See my updated answer for the code.

Comment: But your solution only works when the `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of the Activity and only if the Activity is opened when the receiver gets "called". This feels a little hackie and seams not to be wanted by the Android developers. Instead, using a `Toast` or a `Notification` works fine without these limitations.

Comment: Like you said, it may not be the best option in many situations.  But that doesn't mean there will never be a case where it is the right choice, so it makes sense to know what all your options are.  So I just wanted to be clear that it is, in fact, possible, since that **was** his question.

Answer (score 7):

If your activity is running when the BroadcastReceiver gets the intent you should be able to use `runOnUiThread` to run a method that creates an AlertDialog, e.g.:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            b.setMessage("This is a dialog from within a BroadcastReceiver");
            b.create().show();
        }
    });

}
```

**This works if you make your BroadcastReceiver an inner class to your Activity.**

Answer (score -1):

1) In Activity:

```
public static Context ctx;

onCreate {
    ctx = this;
}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Okay",
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

2) In `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive`:

```
YourActivity ac= new YourActivity ();
ac.showAlertDialog(YourActivity.ctx, "test", "test");
```