# BroadcastReceiver onReceive open dialog

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver

I'm building an android application with `BroadcastReceiver` and I want to show a dialog when `onReceive` starts.
I want to show the dialog on the phone (show the user a dialog no matter where he is, like the whatsapp dialog when you get a message).

How I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: this is the complete example  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41137562/4344659

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show a dialog from inside your `onReceive` of the BroadcastReceiver, inside your broadcast receiver you may start a transparent activity with an alert dialog and NEVER called `setContentView()`. The activity will have an transparent view and only the alert dialog will show. 
*Source:*  [show an alert dialog in broadcast receiver after a system reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot)

There are many similar posts which talk about this topic. See below questions for code samples and other reviews on the same:

2. [AlertDialog from within BroadcastReceiver?? Can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done)
3. [How to raise an alert dialog from BroadcastReceiver class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229951/how-to-raise-a-alert-dialog-from-broadcastreciever-class)
4. [How can I display a dialog from an Android broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835160/how-can-i-display-a-dialog-from-an-android-broadcast-receiver)
5. [How to setup Alertbox from BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332049/how-to-setup-alertbox-from-broadcastreceiver)

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have problem with that, i have 2 activities, and i start the second acticity (the new and not the main), but it's start me the main activity and i dont know why, to the new acticity have class and xml file, and it's work, but i dont know why the recevice start hte main... i do this: Intent i = new Intent(context, BTNotifierWarning.class); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); context.startActivity(i); | but BTNotifierWarning is'nt the main acticity...

Comment: Hey. I am sorry for my previous comment. I thought that its related to this question, so I asked you to edit it. It would be better if you keep the questions separate. Ask a new question for the new problem that you mentioned in the comment. Remove that piece of code from this question. It might confuse others.

Comment: Ok, thanks! this is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906466/how-to-load-activity-from-broadcastreceiver-onreceive