# How to load activity from BroadcastReceiver onReceive

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I want to load an activity from the `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method.
I have 2 activities, one is the main and the second I created.
I want to load the second activity from `onReceive` but it's loading the main activity and I don't know why..

This is the intent on `onReceive()`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, BTNotifierWarning.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

this is the BTNotifierWarning class:

```
package com.btnotifier;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BTNotifierWarning extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.warning);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

and this is the warning xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".BTNotifierWarning" >
```

why it's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the java file name,s chances are you made a mistake.

Comment: the java class name is: BTNotifierWarning.java

Comment: I'm not sure but try using `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: Is your app crashed or only the activity not started? have you add your activity to the manifest?, are you sure your BroadcastReciver is called "onRecive()" ?

Comment: Shobhit Puri, it's not work... JafarKhQ, no, the app is load the main activity (called BTNotifierActivity), but i want to load the activity called BTNotifierWarning, the BroadcastReciver is work, when it's need to load the acitivity, he load the main activity and not the activity i want.

Comment: and yes, the activity is insite the manifest: <activity android:name="com.btnotifier.BTNotifierWarning" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>

Comment: Help? it's urgent for me, very urgent.