# Unable to show alert dialog-android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-internet

I am trying to check internet connectivity from broadcast receiver and if there is not internet want to show an alert dialog but here I receives an error ablove mentioned due to `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` . But if I change it to `AlertDialog.Builder(this)` or `AlertDialog.Builder(NetworkChangeReceiver.this)`, I get compile error. The constructor `AlertDialog.Builder(NetworkChangeReceiver)` is undefined

NetworkChangeReceiver.java

```
package com.example;


public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Inside Network change receiver", Background.isActivityVisible()+"------------------------");
    if(Background.isActivityVisible()==true){
        Boolean status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        Log.d("NetworkChangeReceiver", status+"");
        if(status){
            Log.d("NetworkChangeReceiver", "User Comes online");
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Offline.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            try{
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Lost Internet Connectivity");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you want to retry!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    Boolean status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);  
                    if(status){
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }

                    else{
                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  context.  startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }   catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to show alert dialog in broadcast receiver. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229951/how-to-raise-an-alert-dialog-from-broadcastreceiver-class).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
YourAlertDialog dialog = new YourAlertDialog(mContext);
dialog.getWindow()
    .setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialog.show();
```

And Add system alert permission in your **mainfest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
```

this may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to show alert
>   dialog-android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add
>   window — token null is not for an application

Due to :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

line. because  `AlertDialog.Builder`  require Context of Visible application component like `Activity` instead of `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`,etc.

Currently passing `context` to `AlertDialog.Builder` which is first parameter of  `onReceive` method, is not valid Context to show UI elements.

To show Alert from `BroadcastReceiver`:

**1.** start an Activity with `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` theme and
**2.** show `AlertDialog` in `onCreate` of `Activity`