# [Android]BroadcastReceiver(Action_headset_plug) not firing

Tags: android

I declared a BroadcsastReceiver(Action_headset_plug) in AndroidManifest.xml and defined a  BroadcastHandler.class implement BroadcsastReceiver . I run the apk on the device and the receiver doesn't fire. However , it work correctly when I use registerReceiver() in the Activity. Do I miss something in the AndroidManifest.xml?

This is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="irdc.Earphone_test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver  android:enabled="true" android:name="BroadcastHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".Earphone_testActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

This is the receiver code

```
public class BroadcastHandler extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)){                    
            String mes;
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", 4);
            if(state == 0){    
                mes ="out";   
            }else if(state == 1){    
                mes ="in";           
            }else {         
                mes ="others";
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);        
            builder.setTitle("Headset broadcast");       
            builder.setMessage(mes);      
            builder.setPositiveButton("Okey-dokey", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {              
                    dialog.dismiss();          
                }      
            });       
            builder.create().show();

        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG doesn't show up as one of the options for android.permission

Answer (score 5):

For listening to headset changes, the broadcast receiver cannot be declared in the manifest, it must be dynamically registered. Not all receivers work when declared in the manifest and this is an example where you need to register it programmatically.

You can call this for example in an Activity's **onResume** method or in a Service's **onCreate** method:

```
headsetReceiver = new BroadcastHandler();
registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

Then in the Activity's **onPause** method or in the Service's **onDestroy** method you need to unregister the receiver:

```
unregisterReceiver(headsetReceiver);
```

Comment: Why is this one different from the other ones? Do you have a link to documentation that confirms this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html makes a note for ones that cannot be registered through the app manifest, and this is not one of them.

Comment: However, I was able to get it to work with this method.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The name is wrong in the manifest entry.  Use the full package name, or start it with a period if you want it implicitly appended to the app's package name:

```
<receiver  android:enabled="true" android:name=".BroadcastHandler">
```

Answer (score 0):

Most examples of receivers do not start an AlertDialog but **Toast a message** or create a **Notification** in Status bar. I am sure that you cannot start an Activity because the "content" object stops existing but not if you can built an AlertDialog. ([documentation of Broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html))

So you can try at your receiver a Toast message to make sure that it works.

Example with Notification: http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html

Comment: ["With respect to your error, a manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver is not an Activity, and so it cannot create a dialog."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432601/alertdialog-in-broadcastreceiver/3432645#3432645)