# How do I check if Headset or Internal Microphone is being used for microphone input?

Tags: android

I'm making an app for a specialist purpose that *requires* a headset microphone to be connected. I don't want users to mistakenly use their phone's built-in microphone and have a substandard experience, so ideally the app should enforce a 3.5mm headset to be used.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything about this online, only posts about checking if a microphone is available. I want to instead check for the presence of a headset plugged into the 3.5mm jack.

I can see at least one app where this functionality is present. [Lesser AudioSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch) will display whether my input is from the Headset or Internal Microphone when I connect/disconnect my headset.

How would I achieve this in my own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) broadcast action to detect when a wired headset is plugged.

Note that the broadcast receiver must be registered manually, instead of in the manifest:

```
 yourBroadcastHandler = new BroadcastHandler();
 registerReceiver(yourBroadcastHandler, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
```

And implement a handler for your broadcast:

```
public final class BroadcastHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // Do what you need
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it solves part of the problem. The other issue is, what if the app is launched with the headset already plugged in? In this case, I assume the broadcast wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: It seems this is possible, the app Lesser AudioSwitch (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch) detects when I am using my headset or Internal microphone as microphone input. This is exactly what I need :)

Comment: You should receive the broadcast every time it gets registered, as the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG intent is being broadcast by the system as sticky, meaning that it will be sent to any new BroadcastReceiver being registered.

Comment: Oh interesting, I'll play around with that then. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!
For anyone else looking at this thread, this answer has been taken from this thread (which has an implementation of BroadcastHandler): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481083/androidbroadcastreceiveraction-headset-plug-not-firing
Do you know if this also works for USB-C to Headphone jack converters for phones without headphone jacks?

Comment: @OscarVant, Let me correct you. The answer hasn't been taken from any other one, This is how is done when registering for a broadcast. The fact the other answer names the receiver a BroadcastHandler is coincidental and expected in similar questions, as we developers give sometimes such type of naming as examples, which in this case means  a class for "handling your broadcast". Of course, you could instead also implement a nested anonymous receiver directly when registering for it, but would make the code messy.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't mean that in an accusatory sense. I just thought the link would be helpful to those that wanted more details for actual implementation :)